# How to limit drag and drop capability to only sibling-level elements in angular-ui-tree?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-tree

I am developing a tree view to show list of categories using AngularJS.
I used [this](https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree) git repository.

**HTML**

```
<div ui-tree="treeOptions" id="tree-root" data-drag-enabled="true">
    <ol ui-tree-nodes ng-model="nodes">
        <li ng-repeat="node in nodes"  
            ui-tree-node 
            data-type="top-level" 
            ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'"></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

I am able to implement drag and drop elements in the tree. 
I want to limit the drag and drop capability to only sibling-level elements.

I tried below but still no luck.

**JS**

```
$scope.treeOptions = {

    accept: function (sourceNodeScope, destNodesScope, destIndex) {

        if (sourceNodeScope.$parent.$id === destNodesScope.$parent.$id)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }
}
```

I cannot find much about this requirement on GitHub repository.
Any help or useful link is highly appreciated.

Comment: There is a `beforeDrop` callback that you can use. Basically, inside that callback, check to see whether the dest node passed into it is a sibling of the source node. Then, return a promise that is either resolved or rejected. See the `beforeDrop` notes here: https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree

Comment: Thanks. I did not try `beforeDrop` method yet. I will give a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is basically ok, but the callback you are using is not the right one. Angular-ui-tree has a `beforeDrop` callback that allows you to return a promise, and based on the result, will accept or reject the drop. The `accept` callback is actually called while you are dragging every time you cross another node. Here is a simple sample implementation:

```
$scope.treeOptions = {
        beforeDrop : function (e) {
          if (e.source.nodesScope.$parent.$id === e.dest.nodesScope.$parent.$id) {
            console.log("siblings, this is allowed");
            return $q.resolve();
          }
          else {
            console.log("not siblings");
            window.alert("Not siblings! Reject this drop!");
            return $q.reject();
          }
        }
     };
```

Here is plunkr showing a simple example: http://plnkr.co/edit/6PD6PrD3wRduOjOQzuFN

Comment: I already fixed my problem. Thank you very much. Your tip in question's comment portal helps me to me go through right direction.